# "Double free or corruption" error not thrown when code lines rearranged

Tags: c++, shallow-copy

I am using shallow copy to copy one object to another object and when main() goes out of scope destructors are called and error ": double free or corruption (fasttop):" is thrown which is perfectly fine as I am using shallow copy. Now when I am creating another object between the two copies, it doesn't throws any error, which is bugging me.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int n =5;

    vector vec(n);  
    vector vec1(vec);   
    cout<<vec<<endl;
    cout<<vec1<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which gives output 
[Which is expected as I am using shallow copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qti9.jpg)
Now when I am adding one more object in between, then no error is thrown

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int n =5;

    vector vec(n);  
    vector vec2(n);
    vector vec1(vec);   
    cout<<vec<<endl;
    cout<<vec1<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Which give no error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iegzk.jpg)

Comment: Not sure why you are calling this a shallow copy.  Shallow vs. deep copying only applies when you have pointers (or references).  If you don't have pointers, it is always a deep copy.

Comment: Is this std::vector?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Good point.  Probably not.

Comment: Now you can refer my entire code

Comment: If you know your code has a bug and you aren't getting the behavior you expect, why not just fix the bug?

Comment: @arpitdesai Your `vector` class is doomed for failure since it lacks a copy constructor..

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie And a few other reasons too.

Comment: "Double free or corruption" is **never** perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your code causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).  When your code causes undefined behaviour, anything can happen. You should not expect any particular symptom, such as a crash or a lack of crash.

Your code causes undefined behaviour due to this section:

```
array = new int[0]; 
this->num=n;    
for ( int i=0; i<n; i++)
    array[i]=i;
```

When `n > 0`, you write out of bounds of the allocated space.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. I have to fetch elements in array equivalent to "n". Code is working fine, I am not understanding why double free or corruption error not thrown in second case.

Comment: @arpitdesai you cannot fetch `n` elements from an array of size `0`

Answer (score 2):

One glaring issue is that your `vector` class lacks a user-defined copy constructor.  When you do this in `main`:

```
vector vec1(vec);
```

You are making a shallow copy (copying the pointer values).  You will see that when the destructor of `vector` is called at the end of `main` for both of your `vector` objects:

```
~vector()
{
    delete [] array; // <-- Same pointer value being deleted twice
    cout<<"Base class Dest"<<endl;
}
```

This results in `delete` being called on the same `array` value twice when `main` exits.  This is a double-delete error.

You need to implement a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator to allow proper copying of your `vector` class.   Read up on the  [the rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to ensure that copying the object doesn't cause memory corruption.